# getting a strange output when I expect english strings

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8

The following program reads text from a file named `tes.txt` and separates plain English string from a Urdu String which is same throughout the file. It acts as a stamp after every English word.
The file looks like : *(Urdu string follows English string)*

```
سٹیمپ ختم ہو جاتی ہے

suhail

سٹیمپ ختم ہو جاتی ہے  

gupta

سٹیمپ ختم ہو جاتی ہے

ghazal
سٹیمپ ختم ہو جاتی ہے
```

---

While using windows I compile the following program :

```
import java.io.*;

class checker {
public static void main(String args[]) {
try {
     File f = new File("C:/Users/user/Desktop/tes.txt");
     FileReader reader = new FileReader(f);
     char buffer[] = new char[1024];
     String text = "";
     while( reader.read(buffer) > 0 ) {
        text += buffer.toString();
     }

     String splits[] = text.split("سٹیمپ ختم ہو جاتی ہے");

     for(int i=0;i<splits.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(splits[i]);
     }  
} catch(Exception exc) {
   exc.printStackTrace();
  }
}
}
```

---

as `javac -encoding UTF-8 checker.java`.But when I run this program I get output as `[C@19b49e6`. Why is this ? Also it prints only one string from the array. I also checked the length of buffer array,it comes out to be one. Why one (there is more than one string in the file that will come into the buffer after separating it from a regex)? Where have I made a mistake ?

Comment: For one, you don't want to be calling `buffer.toString()`, but rather creating a new string with the contents of the buffer - something like `new String( buffer, charset )` if memory serves. There may be other problems, too - I'll try to look a little later.

Answer (score 0):

The char buffer[] is not being added to the string properly, change this line.

```
     text += new String(buffer);
```

*Sorry for my previous answer I'm kinda sleepy.

Comment: when you use text += buffer.toString() you are adding to text the representation of the array, not the content of the array. That's not the right way to create a new string from char array

Comment: it is working now but the string `text` is not breaking from the urdu text.[This is what I see as output](http://i47.tinypic.com/10ftjkm.jpg). Also the length of array `split` is coming out to be 1

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is to assume that an array's toString gives you a textual representation of its elements.  It does not.  You want java.util.Arrays.toString(array) for that.

Also, let's say the file has 5 characters in it; you read 5 characters into your buffer of 1024 characters and add all 1024 to your String.  That's 1019 null characters.  I would suggest using BufferedReader.readLine() instead to read a file into a String or even Guava's Files.toString(File file, String charset) - http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toString(java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)

However, to explain how you can fix what you have, you just need to store the number of chars read and only use that many characters from the array.  If that's not clear enough let me know and I'll write a code sample.

Comment: I wrote this [code](http://i47.tinypic.com/idvbpz.jpg),the strings do not split at the Urdu regex and I get [output as this](http://i49.tinypic.com/6qb1vk.jpg) Also length of the split array comes out to be one.

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading in the file content properly, here is a better way to read the content in:

```
 String text = "";
 int readcount=0;
 while((readcount =  reader.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
    text += new String(buffer, 0, readcount);
 }

 String[] splits = text.split("سٹیمپ ختم ہو جاتی ہے");
```